# Order statistic with an additioanl element

Tags: probability, order-statistics

Let $\\X_{(1)},X_{(2)}, \ldots ,X_{(n)}, W $ be an iid sample of distribution with density $f$ which is positive for all $x$. Show that ith $X_{(n)} = \max\{X_{(i)}\}$

$$P(W\le X_{(n)}) =n/(n+1)$$

With an elementary non measure theory approach. How should I go about proving the above claim? I have tried to merge $W$ into the family of order statistic to form a new family with $n+1$ terms though the method doesn't seems to work.

This is not a homework question. It's one that came up in my sample exam paper. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. of  places in between or at the front or back of $X_{(1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)}$ where you can place $W$ is $n+1$. Among these places how many places will get you $W < X_{(n)}$? Can you figure out now?

Comment: Since you mentioned density function, therefore, $P(W < x) = P(W \leq x)$ because the probability of a point in the sample space of a continuous random variable is $0$.

Comment: What do u mean by "non measure theory approach"?

Comment: Why do you have parentheses () around the 1, 2 and 3 in $X_{(1)},X_{(2)}, \ldots ,X_{(3)}$? What do the () denote in your iid sample? What is the meaning of ith  $X_{(n)}$? Why do you have dots between  $X_{(2)} \dots  X_{(3)}$? What are you suggesting lies between them? Say  $X_{(2.5)}$?

Comment: I would say the parentheses suggests the order of the order statistics. Though the above is exactly the same as printed on the sample exam I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot expiTT! I can figure it out via intuitive arugument now! Do you think I can make it more conventional by using the counting principle? Like |A|/|S| where S is the total possible outcome and A the favorable ones?

Comment: Sure. $S$ is the possible number of ways to place $W$ in $X_{(1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)}$ and $A$ is the favorable number of ways. Just for the sake of it I ll post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned density function, therefore, $P(W<x)=P(W\leq x)$ because the probability of a point in the sample space of a continuous random variable is $0$.

Now, no. of places in between or at the front or back of $X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(n)}$ where you can place $W$ is $n+1$. Among these places no. of places which will get you $W<X_{(n)}$ is $n$ (not at the back i.e. not after $X_{(n)}$). So, $P(W \leq X_{(n)} = P(W < X_{(n)}) = \frac{n}{n+1}$.

Comment: What is $n$? The sample size is 3.

Comment: I don't think it is appropriate to change the question to suit your answer. The  OP has noted in the comments that " ... the above is exactly the same as printed on the sample exam I mentioned", so the question stands as is.